# JQuery - Remove everything after an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="i_1"></div>
  <div id="i_2"></div>
  <div id="i_3"></div>
  <div id="i_4"></div>
</div>
```

How do I remove everything after $('#i_2')?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Use `nextAll`

```
$('#i_2').nextAll().remove()
```

Comment: but it removes elements that are at the same level. How do I elements irrespective of their levels after an element contains a certain text?

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#container div:gt(1)").remove();
```

Another alternative.